# difference between last actual and scheduled fire time

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want to get the delay between the time a job was supposed to execute and the time it actually executed for the most recent execution. For example, if a job was supposed to fire at 8pm and it actually fired at 8.10pm, the result should be 10 minutes.

I know that I can use [Trigger.getPreviousFireTime()](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/1.8.5/org/quartz/Trigger.html#getPreviousFireTime%28%29) to get the last time it *actually* executed, but I can't see any way to get the corresponding scheduled time (e.g. 8pm for the example above), is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your job use the following code:

```
@Override
public void execute(final JobExecutionContext context) {
    long diffInMillis =
                new Date().getTime() - context.getScheduledFireTime().getTime();
    //...
}
```

As you probably guessed `context.getScheduledFireTime()` is the time when job was suppose to run (ideally the difference should be close to 0).

Note that if your job is late more than 10 minutes (configurable) it might not fire at all - it depends on your misfire instruction set up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the most recent execution, but you can definetely know for the current execution using the `JobExecutionContext` as @Tomasz says above, plus the API now also offers the `context.getFireTime()` method to avoid the overhead since entering the `execute` method and running the line that subtracts the difference.

So your code can now look like this:

```java
@Override
public void execute(final JobExecutionContext context) {
    //... other (possibly time-consuming) commands
    long actualToScheduledTimeDiffInMillis=
                context.getFireTime().getTime() - context.getScheduledFireTime().getTime();
    //... the rest of your code
}
```